# np.where acting up while comparing time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have the following code:

```
np.where((final_df_SDC['Start Time']>= final_df_SDC['Repayment_Time']) & (final_df_SDC['End Time'] <= final_df_SDC['Repayment_Time']),"OCC","-")
```

which is giving me error : `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'`

However, when I am checking dtypes

```
final_df_SDC['Start Time'].dtype
final_df_SDC['Repayment_Time'].dtype
final_df_SDC['End Time'].dtype
```

I get : `dtype('O')`

Then how is it not comparing?
I tried converting to `pd.datetime(final_df_SDC['Start Time'])` then it said `TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`
I am highly confused now. How do I let all these time values compare with each other?

Sample values : `08:55:18` in this format for all three columns.

SAMPLE VALUES after I converted to astype(str)

```
Start Time  End Time    Repayment_Time
5415    2021-12-01 15:12:24 2021-12-01 15:12:48 2021-12-01 17:41:20
5482    2021-12-01 15:17:05 2021-12-01 15:18:32 2021-12-01 16:33:49
5539    2021-12-01 15:19:40 2021-12-01 15:19:42 2021-12-01 20:02:20
6011    2021-12-01 15:46:18 2021-12-01 15:47:50 2021-12-01 15:51:01
6128    2021-12-01 15:54:20 2021-12-01 15:57:28 2021-12-01 16:00:51
6177    2021-12-01 15:55:44 2021-12-01 15:56:07 2021-12-01 20:00:34
6262    2021-12-01 15:58:28 2021-12-01 15:58:39 2021-12-01 12:11:2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all columns use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with convert to strings:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(final_df_SDC['Start Time'].astype(str))
e = pd.to_datetime(final_df_SDC['End Time'].astype(str))
r = pd.to_datetime(final_df_SDC['Repayment_TimeTime'].astype(str))
```

Or [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
s = pd.to_timedelta(final_df_SDC['Start Time'].astype(str))
e = pd.to_timedelta(final_df_SDC['End Time'].astype(str))
r = pd.to_timedelta(final_df_SDC['Repayment_TimeTime'].astype(str))
```

Then change `<=` with `>=` like:

```
np.where((s <= r) & (e >= r),"OCC","-")
```

Or use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
np.where(r.between(s, e),"OCC","-")
```

Comment: ok i did this but then while comparing is it really comparing the TIME values correctly? because its giving me "-" in all my rows whereas I do have OCC rows as per my data check.

Comment: @coder_bg - can you add some data sample?

Comment: your BETWEEN code line worked but not np.where.. Thank you so much!!

Comment: why is np.where not working??

Comment: @coder_bg - can you test `np.where((s <= r) & (e >= r),"OCC","-")` ?

Comment: I have edited the post with sample values after converting to str as u said

Comment: YES THIS NP.WHERE WORKED!!!! HOW??

Comment: @coder_bg - there was typo, swapped `<=`